# NodeJS Twitter API ничего не выдает

Tags: node.js

Я тут нашел в GitHub'е `twit(NPM)` и согласно него построил следующее приложение:

```
-> express twitter
-> в app.js:

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'AAA',
    consumer_secret:      'BBB',
    access_token:         'CCC',
    access_token_secret:  'DDD'
})

T.post('/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, data, response) {
     console.log(data)
}) // пишу это все после всего кода в app.js созданным express. Но при запуске выдается "undefined"(при `node app.js`) и 404 Not Found в браузере
```

[image: Вот]

Больше ничего не делал и не менял. Кто поможет, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

**Первое**. Вам нужно сначала создать минимальное приложение на express, и уже внутри какого-то обработчика запускать работу с твиттером через модуль Twit.
Express вполне естественно показывает 404. Т.е. должно быть что-то такое:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Здесь запускаем Twit и в обработчике ответа не забываем вызвать res.send
});
```

**Второе**. Вы используете некорректный URI твиттера, нет такого метода API `/update`, есть `statuses/update`. Соответственно если вы сделаете `console.log(response)`, то там будет скорее всего также 404, потому что некорректный метод API.